# After updating SSL Settings Can't Send Email Through SMTP

Tags: c#, ssl, smtpclient

I run a server at home using IIS7.5 and recently ran an SSL test (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest) on it.  It came back with a recommendation to change the cipher suites that I use to eliminate deprecated ones from being used.  I followed the instructions from here: https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html (scroll down to `Microsoft IIS`).  The cipher suites that I am now using came from here: https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html under `1.1 Modern Compatibility`.  Obviously that is the most restrictive.

Now, when I attempt to send an email using `SmptClient` I get the following error:

```
A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
```

Inner Exception:

```
The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
```

I'm sending the emails through `smtp.gmail.com` which I would assume supports modern cipher suites (bad assumption?).

Comment: Have you verified that you are connecting on port 587 for TLS support?

Comment: @SaxxonPike Yes, this was working before I messed with the cipher suites.

Comment: The only thing I can think to do at this point is add ciphers back to the list one by one until you land on one you feel is secure enough, starting with the most secure and working your way down. It's unusual that a service such as Gmail wouldn't support *at least one* of those ciphers, but I can't seem to find a list of all the ones they accept to confirm.

Comment: @SaxxonPike Yeah, I think that's what I'll have to do.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: @MikeH Did you identify which cipher the SMTP connection needed? I am now running into exactly the same issue for exactly the same reason. :-)

Comment: @JonathanGilbert Sorry, I don't recall what I did.

Comment: Thanks anyway -- I figured it out in the end. In my case, it was the older generation SHA-1 hashing algorithm. I thought SHA-2 with its 256, 384 and 512 byte hash lengths would be adequate, but it looks like there are big names out there still using SHA-1 in their certificates and GMail is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

What .NET version do you use? .NET 4.6 uses TLS 1.2 automatically but older versions like .NET 4.5 don't use TLS 1.2 by default. I hope it helps.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; // .NET 4.5
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072; // .NET 4.0
```